# How to updated data in Laravel using version 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

I am trying to update data based on a currently logged-in user and I want to update my data:

This is my controller code:

```
public function submitselectedprofile(Request $request){
    $user = Auth::guard()->user();
    $estimatedInvestorProfile = $request->get('estimatedInvestorProfile');
    $estimatedInvestorProfile = $this->profileArray[$estimatedInvestorProfile];
    DB::table('db_user_registration')->where(['userID'=> $user->id,'estimatedInvestorProfile'=>''])->update(['estimatedInvestorProfile'=>$estimatedInvestorProfile]);

    $portfolio = DB::table('db_portfolio_main')->select('*')->where('UserID', $user->id)->first();
    if(!empty($portfolio)){
        DB::table('db_portfolio_main')->where(['UserID'=> $user->id,'investorProfile'=>''])->update(['investorProfile' =>$estimatedInvestorProfile]);
    }else{
        DB::table('db_portfolio_main')->insert(['UserID' => $user->id,'investorProfile' =>$estimatedInvestorProfile]);
    }
    // return response()->json(['success' => true ], 200);
    return back();
}
```

I am trying to update the data from two tables as you can see

1. From `db_portfolio_main`
2. From `db_user_registration`

But I am unable to update my data from both of my tables, but here I don't know what may be wrong in my query or somewhere else...

Your help will be highly appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please share the exception that you get when trying to do this?
Why you don't use Eloquent classes instead of using the Query Builder?

Comment: i did not get any exception when  i click submit button it load the page and thats it value not updating